# Filtering URL - Google Analytic

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following URLs :

```
example.com/Style/mens/

example.com/deliver/Style/47968/

example.com/49549/Style/
```

My target is:

```
example.com/Style/mens/
```

I need to filter `/Style/` only at the beginning and not in any other place in the URL.

What is the Regex for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
^example\.com\/Style.*
```

This will filter anything like

```
example.com/Style
example.com/Style/something
example.com/Style/something/nothing
```